# After a failed dual-boot install, only Ubuntu boots. How can I remove Ubuntu and boot in Windows again?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm new to Linux, I wanted to install Ubuntu and installed successfully with the Universal USB installer. My notebook has frozen and I was forced to shutdown.

When I started notebook again, it appeared to only boot Ubuntu.

I wanted to have both Windows and Ubuntu and to have possibility to select during the boot.

But unfortunately I can select only Ubuntu.

Now I would like to delete Ubuntu in order to recover all the information that I had on Windows.

I have tried and update-grub, but is not working, I don't have Internet connection.

Comment: Are you certain that you did a dual-boot install? Is it possible you told the Ubuntu installer to wipe the entire HDD by mistake?

Comment: Also, did you install Ubuntu in MBR or UEFI mode? And, was Windows installed in MBR or UEFI?

Comment: Did the notebook freeze during installation or afterwards?

Comment: I would advise against trying to delete anything until you know what data you have where. Deleting something will harm your chances of recovery if you have overwritten your Windows OS.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmq9BmRWmD4

I was following the instruction through this video and at some point my notebook just frozen. Freeze during instalation.

Comment: Each time I read/hear "I've followed a YouTube video" to install Ubuntu I expect the worse. Most of them are rubbish, are made for views by people with a very inflated sense of themselves. Yours was no exception. Please boot the Ubuntu live session again, open GParted, and post a screenshot of your drive.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Please take a look here https://screenshot.net/ew9v7u5. And a question: Is it possible to attach here files?

Comment: There are onky Windows partitions shown. You couldn't possibly have installed Ubuntu in that drive.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have on windows installed daemon tools lite, is it possible to run from there?

Comment: This is not the place for Windows support. This IS the place for situations related to dual-boot with Ubuntu. So far your question is unclear and the screenshot shows no Ubuntu installed. I won't be giving any advice here regarding booting Windows only.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thank you for your time and sorry for taking it, l just don't know where to write with this issue, because look https://postimg.cc/LY04x8dp

Comment: That screenshot shows a not really typical Grub menu but besides that, it suggests you have UEFI and that's ba good thing. I suggest you open UEFI settings, Boot menu or similar (it varies) and from there you may be able to choose "Windows bootloader manager" which should allow booting Windows directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) This is how you make a dual-boit with any Windows 8 or newer in UEFI mode, as it should be. Forget about YouTube videos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) It might be easier to simply fix the Windows bootloader before removing Ubuntu and then complete the Windows bootloader repair from inside Windows: [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/)

Comment: Thank you all, managed to do a boot-repair only when I have connected to the internet with wire. This thread can be closed. Followed 2nd option https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair And now I have back the Windows. @GabrielaGarcia yes you are right I shouldn't followed the youtube instructions. Have a great day.